# mysql produces different result on win7 and debian8

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I am working with a Debian Server with xampp 1.8.3-2 and mysqlserver version 5.6.14 installed. In the old database, latin1_german2_ci was used as character collation for the database and the tables because of the german characters like ä,ö,ü,ß etc.. Now, I have to convert the collation of the tables into utf8_unicode_ci(collate of database is still in latin1_german2_ci). But after that, queries like this don't produce the correct answers anymore. i.e. it not only give everything with `kö` but with `ko` as well. How can I fix this?

```
SELECT * FROM users Where lastname like "%kö%"
```

**edit**: Just found one solution which uses `COLLATE`:

```
SELECT * FROM users Where lastname like "%kö%" COLLATE utf8mb4_german2_ci
```

However, this has to be adjusted depend which server connection collation is used, so if the server connection collation is utf8_unicode_ci, the query has to be changed into

```
SELECT * FROM users Where lastname like "%kö%" COLLATE utf8_german2_ci
```

So my question now: is there a better/more elegant way to solve my problem? Is there any option in the database to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the table's charset to UTF-8 and the collation to utf8_* and make sure there is no _ci and the end (_ci is for "case insensitive") otherwise MySQL will both perform case and accent-insensitive searches.

Comment: first of all, it works then in the way you described. BUT:
1. I can only choose utf_bin without ci at the end, will there be any complication using utf_bin instead of utf_unicode?
2. I need `case insensitive`, so if I'm searching for `kö`, `KÖ, kÖ, Kö` will be found as well. Is there a way to separate case insensitive and accent-insensitive?

Comment: Then use utf8_bin and do something like `WHERE LOWER(lastname) LIKE "%kö%"` it should work, this way it should be case insensitive but accent sensitive

Comment: but in this case, when I search for `Kö`, nothing will be found... so I need to do `WHERE LOWER(lastname) LIKE LOWER(%ko%)`. It maybe ok if I only looking for it in one column, but in real case, there are more then 30 columns in the table and there are multiple tables. Is there no better way? Is there actually no option like a switch in the datebase-configuration where I can just turn on/off case-sensitive or accent-sensitive?

Comment: The problem is ci is both for case and accent, you can't have only one or the other, that why the best solution (in my opinion) is to set utf8_bin and play with lower to have accent sensitive but no case sensitive. Also instead of having both LOWER(lastname) AND LOWER(%Kö%) you could lower directly when you receive your search in php or whatever backend language you're using.